# Remove a row from csv using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to remove the rows from the csv using pandas.

I have the following dataframe

```
Document_ID  offset  JAPE     
    0        0      300       
    0        7      2000      
    0        16     51200      
    0        27     315       
    0        36     51200     
    1        0      2000      
    1        3      300     
    1        4      2200
```

SO here the after removing I am trying to get the output like

```
Document_ID  offset  JAPE     
    0        7      2000      
    0        16     51200         
    0        36     51200     
    1        0      2000         
    1        4      2200  


df = df.drop(df.query('JAPE==315'))
```

can any one help me with this

Comment: Which is the condition to remove the rows?

Comment: I added what I tried